# How does one copy of OS like linux/windows run on different hardware?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-systems

I am an embedded systems developer and I am currently working with PIC 16-bit uC's. Whenever I start to work on a different uC (also PIC 16-bit), there is a considerable change in the peripheral registers and depending on the external pin mapping, I need to predominantly change the pin initialization code, peripheral code and clock settings among other minor things.

**Edit**: 
A typical process of OS installation is, download an ISO image, use a software like Rufus, create a boot-able USB drive and finally install the OS from the live USB.

My questions are:
 i) How does a piece of software (in this context OS) like linux/windows as one file (ISO image) able to run on different motherboards having different processors (Intel/AMD) and different controller chips for  network, audio, video, hard-disk, USB etc?

ii) Firstly how does OS get to know what processor it is talking to ? Secondly, what kind of information is exchanged between OS and microprocessor to understand about all the current hardware configurations so that it can customize its installation software (assuming this is how OS gets to know about different configurations of hardware)?

Comment: As far as I knew, Intel and AMD are all based x86 ISA, they are not exactly 'different processors'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not just *hot swap* an already installed image between two set of hardware.

*having recently tried moving a laptop image to my desktop, and failing, i say this from experience, and theoretics*.

When you run the Windows installer for the first time on a set of hardware - the installer itself will have the essential, bare minimum requirements for getting the most amount of hardware up and running; only those relevant to the hardware you have installed will be copied to your local disk - more complex drivers and updates will be updated by Windows update after you connect to the network.

Simply swapping the image to a new set of hardware will not work; as all supporting libraries, and configurations, were defined for a different set of hardware - it is highly likely you wont get it to easily boot.